# passing keras optimizer as string parameter to keras optimizer function

Tags: python, optimization, keras, deep-learning, parameter-passing

I’m tuning hyperparameters of a `keras` deep learning model with the help of a `config.json` file containing hyperparameters.

```
    { “opt: “Adam”,
      “lr”: 0.01,
       “grad_clip”: 0.5
    }
```

Keras allows to specify an optimizer in two ways:

1. As string argument in call to function without additional parameters.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy’,
              optimizer=’Adam’, 
              metrics=['mse'])
```

2. As eponymous function with additional parameters.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5), 
              metrics=['mse'])
```

My question is: how to pass the optimizer (SGD, Adam etc.) as argument from config file along with the subparameters and employ the `keras.optimizers.optimizer()` function call as in (2)?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional
from keras import optimizers

def train(X,y, opt, lr, clip):

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(500, 300)))    
   model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')))

   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizers.opt(lr=lr, clipvalue=clip), 
                  metrics=['mse'])

   model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

   return(model)
```

When I try to pass parameters from my config file to the above `train()` function, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'opt'
```

How do I parse the optimizer in string from as a function?

Comment: Your latest edit should fix the error you put at the bottom of your question. What error do you get now, if any?

Comment: I've updated the error after rerunning the code. It is more directly related to the issue I raise in the question: how to make a string be parsed as an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class that constructs an optimizer like so:

```
class Optimizer:
    def __init__(self, lr, clip):
        self.lr=lr
        self.clip = clip

    def get_opt(self, opt):
        """Dispatch method"""
        method_name = 'opt_' + str(opt)
        # Get the method from 'self'. Default to a lambda.
        method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: "Invalid optimizier")
        # Call the method as we return it
        return method()

    def opt_Adam(self):
        return optimizers.Adam(lr=self.lr, clipvalue=self.clip)

    def opt_example(self):
        return  optimizers.example(lr=self.lr, clipvalue=self.clip)

    #and so on for how many cases you would need
```

then you can call it as:

```
a=Optimizer(lr, clip)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=a.get_opt(opt=opt), 
              metrics=['mse'])
```

Comment: Do I need to define "lr" and "clip" as class attributes like so: def __init__(self):  self.lr = .0 self.clip = .0, and then refer to them as "self.lr" and "self.clip" in the methods? If so, how does this change affect the call? As is stands, the interpreter complains about undefined variable names in the class declaration and throws an error when code is executed.

Comment: hey! I updated the code, sorry at first I wrote it without testing, it should work now tho :)

Comment: please select the answer as accepted if it solved your issue

Answer (score 3):

At least for tensorflow version 2.11 there is a function to get the optimizer by its name and hand over parameters. Check this for further information: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/get.

To make it short, here is a minimal example for its usage:

```
# read in your config.json file
# KEYS NEED TO BE ADJUSTED TO MAKE THIS WORK CORRECTLY:
# { 
#   “identifier: “Adam”,
#   “learning_rate”: 0.01,
#   “grad_clip”: 0.5
# }

import tensorflow as tf
import json

with open('path/to/config.json', 'r') as f:
    opt_conf = json.load(f)


# define the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# then create the optimizer using the data from opt_conf
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.get(**opt_conf)

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer, 
              metrics=['mse'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a json configuration file which contains the initialization of the optimizers:
eg:

```
"Adam": {
    "lr":0.001, 
    "beta_1":0.9, 
    "beta_2":0.999, 
    "epsilon":None, 
    "decay":0.0, 
    "amsgrad":False
    }
```

Then you can parse it from the configuration using the following lines:

```
with open('configuration.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
```

in the data structure you will find the parameters setup of the optimizer:

```
optimizer = data["Adam"]
```

After all, you can access all the parameters of the chosen optimizer:

```
lr = data["lr"]
beta_1 = data["beta_1"]
etc...
```

An other way is to access the configuration of the optimizer using only the configuration file. Using Keras, you are able to compile your neural network with a specific optimizer  chosen from a configuration file using an optimizer dispatcher:

```
optimizer= {"Adam": keras.optimizers.Adam(**config}
```

keep in mind that the keras optimizer name should be the the same in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the keys of your `csl` object (the config object) actually match those arguments of the classes. Then, the following will create the optimizer object, search for the appropriate arguments from the configuration object, and pass them to it

```
csl = { "opt": "Adam",
  "lr": 0.01,
   "grad_clip": 0.5}
optimizer = eval(f"keras.optimizers.{csl["opt"]}")()
optimizer = optimizer.from_config({k:v for k,v in csl.items() if hasattr(optimizer, k)})
```